# How to stop Mac to convert typing double dash to emdash?

Tags: macos

I think it's a Mountain Lion thing, when you type - (dash) twice, it becomes — (emdash). When you type tm, it becomes ™ (trademark symbol). Or when you type three . (dot), it becomes … (elipsis).  Some are useful, some are very annoying.  Overall, I want to stop that.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just a note for other people reading, that if it's not a OSX thing for you, then it may be your text editor.  I had to change TextEdit with Preferences > Smart dashes.

Comment: wonder what the solution of macOS Sierra is.

Comment: It seems that some apps have to be closed and open for things to work. I was using notes app and it seems it didn't to work until I closed an open the app (completely quit it). It might have been I did `defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled 0`, but who knows.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

(on Sierra 10.12, this is now in the Keyboard control panel)

Go to the system preferences and choose "Language & Text"

[image]

In the "Text" tab you will find the list of substitutions.

[image]

If you want to stop `--` from being turned into `—` (emdash) you need to use the **+** button and add a new rule to replace `--` with `--` (replace with itself)

Or, right click in a text field and go to "Substitutions" and disable "Smart Dashes"

[image: Stupid Dashes]

Comment: that looks awesome and thank you for this answer, but the thing annoys me most "--" to "—" is not there… Hmm…

Comment: ah okay, so if I make another rule as "--" to "--" then it saves my double dashes.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok I thought that it was missing in my case, but I also don't have the substitution. Did it happen in all applications?

Comment: At least, I'm running Mountain Lion in English env, where it happens substitution, it happens. (e.g.: Finda.app, naming a file/directory)

Comment: Adding -- to be replaced by itself does not seem to work in Yosemite (and Keynote) :(

Comment: @BalintErdi I just found this question *again* by googling for the issue, found the answer, thought *Hmmm, this doesn't work, what idiot posted that trick* and then saw it was **own damn edit**. LOL. I just updated the answer, hopefully that works better now!

Comment: `Yosemite 10.2`: Finding a textfield and then clicking in it reveals that `Smart dashes` is disabled by default; and adding the substitution -- for -- doesn't work: typing a double dash in TextEdit still gets converted to a single dash. I tried rebooting--no help.

Comment: `El Capitan 11.11` This is now on the Keyboard control panel.

Comment: in Yosemite 10.10.2 and nothing i can find turns this off. "convert quotes and dashes" has been off for at least a dozen reboots. However, if you hit ⌘z immediately, the substitution is undone.

Comment: Ahhhh `Smart Dashes`, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: I had to close and reopen TextEdit for it to work on Yosemite. No reboot required.

Comment: Usability geniuses :S Thanks man. An important step is the restart of the app.

Comment: it doesn't even let you provide the same text in both for macOS Sierra! How freaking annoying!!!

Comment: Keynote has its own option. Go to edit -> substitutions -> uncheck "smart dashes"

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been very very annoying for the longest of times.

Comment: I had to go to Edit -> Substitutions menue item. The system settings didn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Finally!! Stupic mac

Answer (score 50):

I encountered this same problem on Mavericks (10.9), where the fix has changed slightly.  Go to System Preferences, then "Language & Region" then click the "Keyboard Preferences..." button and to go to "Text" tab.  It is no longer a substitution, however, but instead on the right-hand side of the window there is a tickbox "Use smart quotes and dashes".  Unticking this stops it changing two hyphens into an en-dash.

One little gotcha: on 10.9.5 with TextEdit (and probably others) you must exit then restart your editor to have this change take effect.

Comment: And also disables smart quotes.  I have no idea why Apple decided to lump those two into the same bucket in the preferences.  Fortunately, you can disable them individually under Edit > Substitutions, though that behavior is per-app.

Comment: In 10.11 El Capitan at least, it's possible to disable just smart dashes (while keeping smart quotes) by running `defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled 0` from the terminal.  There are two separate settings under the hood, `NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled` and `NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled`, both of which get toggled by the UI checkbox "Use smart quotes and dashes".  But there's no guarantee from Apple that this won't change in future versions of OS X.

Comment: thanks a lot @AdamRosenfield, your solution is by far the best listed here.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, you should elevate this comment to an answer so we can vote for it. :-)

Comment: you sure this works? Do I need to reboot my Mac or restart my apps?

Comment: For consistent results, I had to close the app (Notes in my case) and System Preferences (Keyboard prefs window).

Answer (score 28):

In 11.11 this is under `System Preferences` > `Keyboard`. There is a checkbox for `Use smart quotes and dashes`.

Keyboard pref in 11.11

[image]

Comment: Except that doing that also disables smart quotes, which you probably *don't* want to do.  Turning off smart dashes under Edit > Substitutions fixes the problem more cleanly (turning off just the dashes), with the caveat that the behavior is per-app.  (Why!?!)

Comment: Why would you want smart quotes? I've always considered those a solution to a problem that never actually existed. They are also especially horrid for programmers.

Comment: you sure this works? Do I need to reboot my Mac or restart my apps?

Comment: @dgatwood So not all applications support Edit > Substitions. In Slack for instance I see no solution other than to disable both as this answer suggests doing. +1 for this answer (although I don't mind smart quotes if type them in)

Comment: For consistent results, I had to close the app (Notes in my case) and System Preferences (Keyboard prefs window).

Answer (score 22):

In earlier versions of Mac OS X, there were two separate options for smart quotes and smart dashes in the Keyboard System Preferences; however in at least versions 10.9 through 10.11, that option has been replaced by a single "Use smart quotes and dashes" preference.

Fortunately, there are still two separate preferences under the hood, and the UI checkbox toggles both of them simultaneously.  You can enable or disable just one of smart quotes or smart dashes from the terminal:

```
# Disable just smart dashes
defaults write -g NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled 0

# Disable just smart quotes
defaults write -g NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled 0

# To re-enable, set either back to 1.
```

This is currently true as of OS X 10.11; this may change in future versions of OS X (or macOS, as it will now be called).

Comment: Still works as of 10.12.6 - thank you!

Comment: Still works on 10.13 as well.

Comment: Still works on 10.15.2!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work under Big Sur 11.6.3 ...

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you folks are still having this problem but I just discovered how frustrating it can be. I was writing a unix script for Apple Remote Desktop which requires a `--get` flag and it kept getting converted to an em dash, ruining the command.

I couldn't find a way to turn off the em dash conversion, but all hope is not lost. In the Language & Text menu (Text tab) I created an entry that replaces `--` with `--` (i.e. it replaces two dashes with itself). This overrides the system converting `--` to an em dash.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work under Big Sur 11.6.3 and Powerpoint for Mac, Version 16.60. I couldn't find the double-dash settings in Powerpoint's "Autocorrect" option panel, so I hoped that a "global" Mac system pref setting will cure this nonsense. It didn't :-(

Answer (score 4):

It's worth mentioning that even with "use smart quotes and dashes" enabled, you can still "undo" the auto-conversion of -- to — (emdash) by pressing CMD+Z. If turning smart dashes off completely sounds too extreme, this is one way to bring back the -- (double dash).

Also, here's my horror story about “curly quotes:” I had been using [Github](https://github.com/) for years and wondered why my "contributions" never appeared correctly on my profile. I eventually discovered I had configured my git user name in terminal with curly quotes instead of straight marks:

```
git config --global user.name “Steve”       //instead of...
git config --global user.name "Steve"
```

Even though I was copy/pasting the command directly from [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/), TextEdit was “fixing” my quotes before I put them in Terminal. Unbelievable! This drove me insane, but I'm recovering...

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is controlled by a system default.  To turn it off, type at the terminal:

```
    defaults write -app 'Keynote' TSWPAutomaticDashSubstitution 0
```

or

```
    defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' TSWPAutomaticDashSubstitution 0
```

The first turns off dash substitution for a particular app (here, *Keynote*); the second for all apps that don't have their own, overriding, default set explicitly.  Replace `0` by `1` to turn dash substitution back on.

As other replies here have stated, the global default can also be changed using *System Preferences* (Keyboard>Text>Checkbox "Use smart quotes and dashes"), but this turns on and off *quote* substitution *as well as* dash substitution.  Moreover, some apps, but not all, allow you to change their defaults by control-clicking in a text field and selecting *Substitutions* or *Show Substitutions*.  For example, *Mail* lets you do this, but *Keynote* does not.

If you want to turn on quote substitution, say, for *Keynote* use

```
defaults write -app 'Keynote' NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled 1
```

or, to turn it on for everything that does not have an overriding default, use

```
defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled 1
```

To turn it off, use `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: For Slack, where this was driving me crazy, I think the setting key is `WebAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

In you're using Apple "Office" tools: Page, Number, etc, the settings in System Preferences or the command line defaults command as mentioned in previous answers won't affect the smart substitutions. Instead, you'll have to go to top tool bar Edit > Substitutions menu to check or uncheck 'Smart Quotes', 'Smart Dashes' etc.

If you're using TextEdit then 7stud's answer is the way, which is included here for completeness: TextEdit > Preferences and check/uncheck the settings in the bottom sections.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to prevent this from happening on occasion, or per some specific instance, you can simply wait for Mac to make the unwanted change and then press `CMD+z` to undo.

Comment: Have you tested this with the "--' and "—" to confirm this works as expected as described by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

`Yosemite 10.2 and TextEdit`:

1. Launch TextEdit.
2. TextEdit>Preferences
3. In bottom right corner, uncheck `Smart dashes` .
4. If your TextEdit file is open, close it and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> will prompt the list of emoji.

Search on "dash" by starting typing.
And you will get this filtered list:

- Use the 7th emoji twice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Ventrua 13.5.2, you can find above menu in [System Preferences]->[Keyboard] ->[Text Input] -> [Input Sources] -> [Edit...]-> [Use smart quotes and dashes]

1. [System Preferences]->[Keyboard] ->[Text Input] -> [Input Sources]
   [image]
2. [Edit...] -> [Use smart quotes and dashes]

[image]