# Double (or more) dash turned to one, while typing (Mojave)

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, dash

After following the suggestions here [How to stop Mac to convert typing double dash to emdash?](https://superuser.com/questions/555628/how-to-stop-mac-to-convert-typing-double-dash-to-emdash) and disabling `Smart quotes and dashes` and even replacing the text of `--` to `--`, when I try to type a double dash, it automatically gets replaced by a long single dash. 
Even more dashes than two are getting replaced by a long single dash of the corresponding length.

e.g.

`--` automatically translates to `—`,

`------` automatically translates to `——————`

Also this happens system-wide, at all apps, with a few exceptions (like when writing a URL at a browser). Is there a way to get rid of that behavior?

The current version of OS X is Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Disabling "smart quotes and dashes" should do the trick. Have you restarted the affected apps (e.g. TextEdit)?

Comment: Indeed I have. Restarted all the apps and then restarted the system too. Still the same reaction.

Comment: Do you have anything else interfering with text input? Some other apps?

Comment: @slhck No. It is a brand new laptop.