# How do you stop PowerPoint or macOS from converting double-dashes to em dashes?

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint, macos-sonoma

Is there a way to stop PowerPoint or macOS from converting double-dashes ("--") to em dashes ("—")?  Context:  I am using a text box in a slide in PowerPoint for Mac v16.78 on a MacBook Pro running macOS Sonoma 14.0.  Sometimes I need to write sample shell code with flags (each led by "--") in PowerPoint text boxes, and this feature ruins the flags.

A similar question was asked years ago in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/555628/how-to-stop-mac-to-convert-typing-double-dash-to-emdash), but the macOS has changed, and the remedies discussed in this thread don't seem to work in this context.

The remedies I have tried unsuccessfully to date:

- In PowerPoint, disabled all AutoCorrect features
- In PowerPoint, entered "--" as a replacement for "--"
- In PowerPoint, entered "--" as a replacement for "—"
- Under macOS System Settings > Keyboard > Text Replacements, set Replace "--" with "--"; tried "--" as a replacement for "—"; also tried no replacements at all
- Under macOS System Settings > Keyboard > All Input Sources (currently "U.S." English), disabled "Correct spelling Automatically" and "Use smart quotes and dashes"
- In PowerPoint and macOS, tried designating "--" as a replacement for alternate text (for example, "++"), but replacement doesn't happen

The main work-around I have found to date is using command+Z to undo each text substitution right after it happens.  Also, you can draft the text in a text editor and then paste it into a slide all at once, but there must be a better way.

Update 1:  I learned that running `defaults --help` in Terminal provides some information about reading and writing (resetting) current default settings.  ChatGPT-4 contributed the following code to identify which domains include a setting related to dash substitution:

```
# Loop through each domain
for domain in $(defaults domains | tr ',' '\n'); do
    # Check if the domain contains settings related to dash substitution
    result=$(defaults read "$domain" 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'dashsubstitution')
    
    if [ ! -z "$result" ]; then
        echo "Domain: $domain"
        echo "$result"
        echo "-------------------------"
    fi
done
```

In my case, this returned four settings:

```
Domain: com.ampl.ide.rcp.product
    NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = 0;
-------------------------
Domain: com.apple.iBooksX
    TSWPAutomaticDashSubstitution = 1;
-------------------------
Domain: com.apple.iChat.inputLine
        automaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = 0;
-------------------------
Domain: org.tempel.findanyfile
            NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = 0;
-------------------------
```

The general format for changing these is as follows:

```
defaults write [Domain] [Key] [Value]
```

So you could change a setting like this (setting the boolean value to true ("1") or false ("0"), as needed).  Of course, you should take note of the initial setting before changing anything.

```
defaults write com.apple.iBooksX TSWPAutomaticDashSubstitution -bool false
```

Running the code above changed the targeted setting as expected, but it did not solve the underlying issue of uncommanded em dash substitution.  The following commands work individually for searching a relevant domain for settings using certain keywords, but it appears to me the behavior I am seeing has been hard-coded into PowerPoint.

```
defaults read com.microsoft.Powerpoint | grep -i 'dash'
defaults read com.microsoft.Powerpoint | egrep -iR 'dashsub'
```

I am still looking for a fix.

This problem has been reported to Microsoft through PowerPoint using Help > Feedback, which you could do as well if you would like to support a product update.

Comment: PowerPoint is likely to have its own 'ignore what macOS thinks, do it the MS way' pref somewhere. I don't use it so I can't check, but it's often the case.

Comment: Thanks harrymc. That was the thread I linked to my question.  It was helpful but did not solve the problem.  That's for an older macOS.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. Have you tried in PowerPoint to AutoCorrect emdash to `--`?

Comment: harrymc:  Yes, actually I did try that.  I just tried again and it didn't work.  It's as if macOS is ignoring the AutoCorrect preferences in PowerPoint.  To Tetsujin's point, I'm not aware of a way to get PowerPoint to ignore what macOS thinks, or to effectively change what macOS is doing.